# Some port forwarding not working on vagrant

Tags: hadoop, vagrant, virtualization, hortonworks-data-platform, vagrantfile

My Host OS - Linux Mint17 and Guest OS is CentOS 6.5

I am trying to forward 3 ports in vagrantfile but only 1 port is actually working from host.

Vagrant File Contents:

```rb
node.vm.hostname = "node.xyz.com"

#namenode endpoint
node.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 50070, host: 50070
#yarn endpoint
node.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 8088, host: 8088
#ambari endpoint
node.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 8080, host: 8080
```

Once machine is UP and if type "localhost:8080" it works fine but if i type "localhost:8088" or "localhost:50070" it does not work and says "Connection reset".

When I do "curl" , below is output

```
$ ~/at/vagrant/single_node_ambari $ curl -XGET localhost:50070
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
$ ~/at/vagrant/single_node_ambari $ curl -XGET localhost:8088
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
```

I tried disabling iptables as well.

Comment: Is any service listening on the port in question?

Comment: yes.. at 50070 is to access Hadoop Namenod Web UI

Comment: Can you ssh into your vagrant box and do the same curl to see if it's an issue with the ports or the services running on the box?

Comment: Also, what does the output from `vagrant up` look like? It should tell you whether Vagrant thinks the port forwarding was set up correctly or not.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use an other centos6.5 box.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same issue. I found that difference between working(7180) and non-working ports (8888) by netstat command

```
"netstat -an | grep LISTEN | grep 8888"
tcp        0      0 <private ip>:8888      0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
"netstat -an | grep LISTEN | grep 7180"
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:7180            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

Login in to the cloudera manager and go to the configuration -> Search address -> enable "Bind Hue Server to Wildcard Address" to "Hue Server Default Group" and restart the service. Same process will be applied for other nonworking ports.